# VisualStudio 2013 Stability with Desktop Application

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am planning to switch from VS2010 to VS2013. I am vb programmer. Just need to confirm is this version stable or what sort of issues I may face if there any. I use to develop desktop Database application like POS etc. 
Appreciate your comments.

Comment: Check the release notes for information like this:  https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-update4-rtm-vs

Answer (score 0):

Well, its a well stabled version. I recently switched from VS2008 to VS2013 and its way more good than VS2008 or VS2010.

Until now, i just found one problem with the VS2013.

If you are planning to use Crystal Reports for report development, you will be disappointed. There is no version of Crystal Report that embeds in VS2013.

Other than, if you are mainly developing db Applications, go explore the VS2013. You will not be disappointed for sure.